# AWS: Getting 502 from Application LoadBalancer to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group, amazon-elb

I have 2 EC2 instances in 2 public subnets. The EC2 instances are fronted my an Application Load Balancer in the same public subnet as the EC2 instances. The Security groups for the EC2's is set to only accept tcp traffic from the security group the load balancer is in.

I am getting a 502 when I hit the Application Load Balancers endpoint.

I am deploying using CloudFormation. Here is the relevant bit of code.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Deploy a 3-tier wordpress system. (Plublic and Private subnets and DB on RDS)

Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC id
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-0b6a616f830dd7d5a

  PublicSubnetA:
    Description: Subnet Id where instance will create
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-0616a6183bee2b276

  PrivateSubnetA:
    Description: Subnet Id where instance will create
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-06784a19612a64444

  PublicSubnetB:
    Description: Subnet Id where instance will create
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-04f7e39ac1431f22a

  PrivateSubnetB:
    Description: Subnet Id where instance will create
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-0fa6aa79eaee582bf

  EC2KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: test
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.

  EC2InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.

  WebServerInstanceAMI:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
    Default: ami-0210560cedcb09f07
    ConstraintDescription: must be an existing AMI ID.

  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: 9
    MaxLength: 18
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: (\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

  Application:
    Description: Application Name
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "[A-Za-z0-9-]+"
    Default: test

  Environment:
    AllowedValues: [preprod,prod]
    Default: preprod
    Description: The name of the Environment
    Type: String

Resources:
  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      GroupDescription: ELB Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: 80
          IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          ToPort: 80
          Description: Allow from internet
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${Application}-loadbalancer-sg'
        - Key: Project
          Value: !Ref Application
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'SSH and Port 80'
      VpcId:
        Ref: VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: !Ref 'SSHLocation'
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            Ref: LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${Application}-webserver-sg'
        - Key: Project
          Value: !Ref Application
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: ApplicationLoadBalancer
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnetA
        - !Ref PublicSubnetB
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref ApplicationTargetGroup
  ApplicationTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 15
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      HealthCheckPath: /index.html
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Name: ApplicationTargetGroup
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: '20'
      Targets:
        - Id: !Ref WebServerInstance1
          Port: 80
        - Id: !Ref WebServerInstance2
          Port: 80
  WebServerInstance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref EC2InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref EC2KeyName
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup
      ImageId: !Ref WebServerInstanceAMI
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          cd /tmp
          sudo yum update -y
          sudo yum install -y httpd
          echo "Welcome from the instance 1" > /var/www/html/index.html
          sudo -u root service httpd start
  WebServerInstance2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref EC2InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref EC2KeyName
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetB
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup
      ImageId: !Ref WebServerInstanceAMI
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          cd /tmp
          sudo yum update -y
          sudo yum install -y httpd
          echo "Welcome from the instance 2" > /var/www/html/index.html
          sudo -u root service httpd start
Outputs:
  LoadBalancerDnsName:
    Description: Load Balancer public facing DNS
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-LoadBaancer
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
```

I have a look at the resources deployed in the console UI and I can see the correct security group rules on the EC2 instances. I don't see when the ALB would have trouble sending messages to the EC2 instances.

Question: Why am I getting a 502 error when I hit the ALBs endpoint?

Comment: Have you checked if the web server is running?

Comment: What about vpc configuration? Is it custom vpc?

Comment: @MarkoE your right, the webserver was not working. Any idea why my user data script did not start the server?

Comment: @Marcin yup, it is a custom VPC.

Comment: Can you provide full details of the template? VPC? You haven't even specified what AMI are you using.

Comment: Added the full template, I have double-checked that the 2 public subnets have an internet gateway in the route table.

Comment: @DrkStr I would check `cloud-init-output.log` in `/var/log`. It should show you if there were any errors. You could also check the logs of the service itself, or simply run `systemctl status httpd`.

Comment: Looking at the user data part, I would maybe switch from `sudo -u root service httpd start` to `sudo systemctl start httpd`.

Comment: You have to tag @Marcin ppl in comments. Otherwise, they don't get notifications of your replies.

Comment: @MarkoE @Marcin updating the start command to `sudo systemctl start httpd` made it work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DrkStr That was not the cause of the issue. I run your code with `sudo -u root service httpd start` and it works. You must have made changes to your VPC or used different subnets of it.

Answer (score 0):

I **deployed** your template in my VPC. The **template is perfectly fine** and works without any issues, including your load balancer and the website.

Thus whatever is causing your issues, is outside of this template. Probably **VPC definition** is incorrect, but it is not showed. You can make new question with details of your VPC setup if you want.